# WSOD appears in Drupal

Tags: 7, commerce

During making of new variants performing steps.
node edit form->add new variant->variant type ->panel->selection rules->node type->context continue->choose layout 2 column->continue->render->standard->continue after this white display occur,i am stuck here.what is the problem.

Comment: Blank pages or "white screen of death" (WSOD) https://drupal.org/node/158043

Comment: thanks but i have already seen this what i need a shortcut for panels.i thinks its some issue with modules.

Comment: yes no error was there in logs.

Answer (score 1):

There are some PHP settings that can lead to WSOD. These are as follows:

1. **max_execution_time:** Apparently, on WAMP, the default is 30 seconds,
   but some administrative pages may take longer than that to process
   and load.

> Go to XAMPP/php/php.ini and change :

```
    max_execution_time = 360
```

1. **PHP Memory Limits:** Another common reason for the WSOD is issues with
   memory limit.

   ```
   memory_limit = 128M
   ```

Comment: thanks..i am using commerce kickstart some issue with panels compatibility with ctool...

Comment: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in var/www/mysite/htdocs/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/ctools/plugins/content_types/token/token.inc this error comes now what to do next.?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be able to find the issue if you can come to know the error that is causing the problem, as the error reporting is by default turned "OFF" to avoid end user know the internal error for security and other purposes, so enabling the error on local or on dev server might help you out, try adding the following code in **settings.php**:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

**Note**:- Remove the above code from settings.php file once you are done with the development work.

Also check the errors/exceptions logged in the **watchdog** table in drupal at "**/admin/reports/dblog**":

```
http://YOUR_WEBSITE_DOMAIN/admin/reports/dblog
```

Also please check this link: **[Blank pages or "white screen of death" (WSOD)](https://drupal.org/node/158043)** for other possible solutions to WSOD.

Comment: @user3459111: Have you checked the issue queue of ctools module ("Unsupported operand types error in plugin/content_types/token/token.inc"): https://drupal.org/node/1624460